# ¿Como puedo restar el contenido de un array en java?

Tags: java

Estoy estudiando programación y no es mi fuerte precisamente. Me gustaría saber cómo realizar restas de un array de enteros. Ej:

```
int[]resta=new int[5];

resta[0]=5;

resta[1]=5;

resta[2]=3;

resta[3]=1;

resta[4]=2;

//Total=-6
```

La pregunta es como podría realizar el bucle para que se vaya restando cada posición del array

```
... 
for(...){
...

}
```

Lo quiero hacer sin ir nombrando cada posición que quiero restar (automáticamente por así decirlo).

Comment: Luis Mengíbar, buenos días, aún no he podido resolver este método de resta, y le dado vueltas haber si me funciona, me puedes hacer el favor de indicarme como se puede resolver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal y como indicas se haría con un bucle `for`. En primer lugar necesitarías calcular el número de elementos del array:

- En Java es tan sencillo como escribir `nombredelarray.length`.
- En cambio en c++ es algo más complicado y lo mejor sería que supieras de antemano el número de elementos que tiene, si no es el caso podrías hacer `sizeof(nombredelarray) / sizeof(nombredelarray[0])`, este proceso como ves es mucho más incómodo, lo que estas haciendo es calcular el tamaño de tu array completo y dividirlo por el tamaño de uno de sus elementos, de tal forma de que si por ejemplo el array completo ocupa 32 bytes y cada uno de sus elementos ocupa 4 bytes pues ya sabes que son 8 elementos (32 / 4 = 8).

Por el código que has puesto supongo que será un array de java por ello lo primero que tienes que crear una variable que contenga su tamaño:

```
int tamano_array = resta.length;
```

Ahora vamos a necesitar otra variable donde ir guardando el resultado de cada una de las restas, por ello crearemos una variable de tipo entera y tal y como son tus requisitos la inicializaremos con el valor del primer elemento del array:

```
int resultado_resta = resta[0];
```

Finalmente, una vez que tengas la longitud de tu `array` y la variable donde se van a ir acumulando todas las restas, ya podriamos usar un bucle, yo te recomendaría en este caso el bucle `for`, pero realmente con ingenio puedes usar cualquiera.

```
for (int i = 1; i < tamano_array; i++)
{
    resultado_resta = resultado_resta - resta[i];
}
```

Este bucle lo que está haciendo es crear una variable de tipo entero llamada `i` que empieza con el valor `1` ya que el primer elemento de tu array es con el que empiezas a restar. En cada vuelta del bucle va a sumar su valor en `1` y va a salir antes de alcanzar el tamaño de tu array, esto es importante porque en programación como todos los arrays empiezan en 0, terminan en su número de elementos - 1 (tamano_array - 1).

En cada iteración del bucle lo que está ocurriendo es que la variable tendría su valor menos el siguiente elemento del array.

Comment: Gracias es justo lo que necesitaba, lo he entendido perfectamente.